# SQLite importing CSV with Japanese text

Tags: sqlite, unicode, openoffice.org

I created a table in OpenOffice spreadsheet, saved it as a CSV file. It had one column in English and the others in Japanese. 
I imported it into SQLite but no matter how I encode it (there are lots of options), for example UTF-8, 日本語　Windows, etc., when the table is imported the Japanese columns are all mixed up symbols and gibberish. At the point of madness I even went for ASCII encoding, but nothing worked.

I can manually input the fields and the Japanese shows up great. But I would literally need to do this a thousand times by hand if I OPenOffice and SQLite don't play nice.

Please help.

Comment: I can't help you but I can tell you you're more likely to get help from someone who knows the answer if you go back and mark the accepted answers on your previous questions.

Comment: Ooops. Did it. Sorry and thank you for reminding me.

Comment: Please describe your env and procedures. Specially Windows version and Japanese edition or other countries edition. Also needs OpenOffice version and importing method.

Comment: today, i tried similar combination. OS:Linux(Debian/squeeze) OO-3.2.1.sqlite3:3.7.3. Lang=ja_JP.utf-8. I did not find any problems.

Comment: I'm using Windows7 OO 3.2 sqlite3.7.2. I think the problem is with the SQlite. Because I can save the japanese text as utf8 and the csv file is ok. Maybe SQlite encodes it in another format.

Comment: I suspect that SQLite doesn't read the CSV file as UTF8, and you are seeing garbled Western European or other iSO 8859 interpretation of the file.

Answer (score 0):

As a dead-sure way you can convert it to HTML with PHPs Multibyte functions and transfer it as ASCII.